# {Python, Selenium} How can I detect browser windows that I'm already using and create a new tab inside said browser window?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

I am currently working on a auto log-on for a website, but I found that selenium opens a new browser window each time I run the script. I want to make it so that it opens a new tab in the browser window I am already using. Selenium opens a new browser window, like so:
[image]

However, I want it to detect a window I am already using, and place a new tab there, like so:[image]

Can we do this with Selenium for Python or do I need another language?
Sorry if my question is a bit stupid.

Thanks!

Comment: you can open a new tab using javascript: driver.execute_script("window.open('about:blank', '_blank');");   You can then switch the driver to that tab.  However, it sounds like you are creating a new webdriver for each script.  That will create a separate webdriver/browser.

Answer (score 0):

There are no stupid questions.
You need to find the reason why your selenium is opening new browser each time you log in.

It is probably because you are initialize webdriver each time you run that method.
Or maybe you use some hooks or tags which are triggering creation of new webdriver.

The code form other user from this site:

driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 't')
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.TAB)

windows = driver.window_handles

time.sleep(3)
driver.switch_to.window(windows[1])